# Excel VBA: running IE.ExecWB 12,2 with locked screen returns "Method 'ExecWB' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed"

Tags: excel, vba, windows, internet-explorer, lockscreen

The following simple code works fine as long as the screen isn’t locked. If it is run when the screen is locked (Ctrl+Alt+Del, Alt-K) then it returns error code 80040100 “Method 'ExecWB' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed"

- Running Excel 2019 on Windows 10, 64bit on simple home PCs/network
- This routine has worked for years without problems.
- The problem started in the last week or so and is the same on two different Win 10 PCs. One PC has all latest updates, the other for some reason fails to download the latest cumulative updates. I am not aware of any other changes that have been made.
- I have tried using InternetExplorerMedium

Any idea what has gone wrong?

```
Sub CopyURLSheet_Slim()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Sleep (3000) ' user locks screen
    
    On Error GoTo Err_Clear
    
    With IE
        .silent = True
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.morningstar.com"
        
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4 ' 4 = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Wend
        
        WriteLog ("Log3..")
        IE.ExecWB 17, 0  'SelectAll
        
        WriteLog ("Log4..")
        IE.ExecWB 12, 2  'Copy selection - CAUSES ERROR 0040100 Method 'ExecWB' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed
        
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("MS_url").Select
        
        WriteLog ("Log7..")
        Sheets("Sheet1").PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
        
        .Quit
    End With
    
Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        WriteLog ("Error: " & Hex(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description)
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
    
Err:
    Set IE = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

```
Output
Log3
Log4
Error: 80040100 Method 'ExecWB' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed
Log7
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. The code works well when I lock the screen. You can try to disable the protected mode in IE settings for testing purpose to check whether it solves the error or not. Besides, you can clear cache completely to see if it can fix the issue. You can also try `Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")`.

Comment: Thank you, but porotected mode makes no difference, I have tried deleting cache and reinstalling IE11. Your set statement caused "1CE The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"?

Comment: That's so strange. The code works well on my side. What about running `taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe` in Command Prompt with administrator privilege, then run the VBA code?

Comment: That also makes no difference sadly, and I tried rebooting.  I also quite everything in the system tray which made no difference. I have also found that if I add a long enough Sleep() for the Screensaver to kick in (with Login at resume checked) that it usually works properly, but sometimes it has caused the same problem (not sure why this is intermittent).

Comment: I can't think of other causes of the issue. You can try to move from IE to Edge as IE 11 desktop application will go out of support and be retired on June 15, 2022 for certain versions of Windows 10. You can have a try with Edge WebDriver using Selenium to automate Edge browser.

Comment: I think you are right, but I've been trying to dodge Selenium as it's a lot of new stuff to learn, and I think it isn't portable (which is a real pain but not a show stopper). You don't know a good tutorial for basic web scraping, and logging into a website (just a simple username/password) by any chance?  Also what is Excel going to do with the Data->From Web function which is still utter rubbish and based on IE11!!!???

Comment: You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) about how to use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge. For the **Data->From Web** function, I think it will still use MSHTML/Trident engine as the IE retirement will only affect IE 11 desktop application on some versions of Windows 10. For more information about IE 11 retirement, you can refer to [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549).

Comment: Still trying to find a solution to this without massive rewriting of my VBA code. It works with screen saver  + display log-on with resume. But it doesn't work with Screen Lock (e.g. when waking from sleep). Any ideas anyone? Exactly the same on my laptop and desktop. I have tried quitting every system tray app etc to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can write **Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))** before **IE.ExecWB 12, 2**,it works for me.Reference is come from [here](https://gist.github.com/Stephanevg/82928b1af35e9812ae632180beebe692)

Comment: I tried but this but it didn't help unfortunately. Still getting "Error=80040100 Method 'ExecWB' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed" on executing "IE.ExecWB 12, 2"